# Javascript loop json data into html forEach issue

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to parse the json to html.

- Looping the data with a forEach function has an issue. Not sure why?
- also the values aren't displaying properly.
- I'd like to be able to have the data displayed and looped into html.

```js
async function fetchData() {

  const response = await fetch('https://assets.cmcmarkets.com/json/cmc-test-most-popular-feed.json');
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data)


  data.forEach(obj => {

    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {

      console.log(`${key} ${value}`);

      const Name = document.querySelector('.name'),
        Code = document.querySelector('.code'),
        Spread = document.querySelector('.spread'),
        CellA = document.querySelector('.cellA');


      if (key == "name") {
        Name.innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${value}</div>`;
      }

      if (key == "code") {
        Code.innerHTML = `<div>Code: ${value}</div>`;
      }

      if (key == "spread") {
        Spread.innerHTML = `<div>Spread: ${value}</div>`;
      } else if (key == "1day") {

      }

      //  data["X-ABFDN"]['1day']  data["X-ABAAA"]['1day']  data["X-AQWER"]['1day']
      else if (key == "1day") {
        CellA.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["movement"]}</div><div>price: ${data[key]["price"]}</div>`;

      }


    });


  });

}

fetchData();
```

```html
<div class="name"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="spread"></div>
<div class="cellA"></div>
```

Comment: Please add some more details. What isn;t working? Any errors? Desired output? First thing: `Object.entries(data)` isn't very clear. Did you ment `Object.entries(obj)`?

Comment: `data` from [this endpoint](https://assets.cmcmarkets.com/json/cmc-test-most-popular-feed.json) is just an object, there is no array wrapping it, so I think you need to just delete the `data.forEach(obj...)` loop and have `Object.entries(data).forEach(...)` be the only loop.

Comment: @James Thanks, solved the forEach one. Now I don't have anything rendered and displayed on html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` in itself is an `object`, so if you want to display it's `name`, you would use `value.name`. Remove one `forEach` level from your code and iterate through the keys/values of the retrieved data (where each value is an `object`).

With that in mind, one way to display data is to create a block of elements per object entry, using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Something like:

```js
fetchData();

async function fetchData() {
  const data = await fetch(
      'https://assets.cmcmarkets.com/json/cmc-test-most-popular-feed.json' )
    .then( r => r.json() );
  
  Object.entries(data).forEach( ([key, value]) => 
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `
        <div class="datablock">
          <div class="name">Name: ${value.name}</div>
          <div class="code">Code: ${value.code}</div>
          <div class="spread">Spread: ${value.spread}</div>
          ${value.cellA ? `<div class="cellA">cellA: ${value.cellA}</div>` : ``}
          ${value["1day"] ? `
            <div class="movement">Movement: ${
              value["1day"].movement}</div>
            <div class="price">Price: ${
              value["1day"].price || `unknown`}</div>` : ``}
        </div>`)
    );
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}

.datablock {
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  Note that each time through the loop, you are replacing the previous iteration values with new content, which isn't ideal.  You'll probably have to create new output elements for each iteration through the loop.

```
async function fetchData() {

  const response = await fetch('https://assets.cmcmarkets.com/json/cmc-test-most-popular-feed.json');
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data)

  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, obj]) => {

    const Name = document.querySelector('.name'),
      Code = document.querySelector('.code'),
      Spread = document.querySelector('.spread'),
      CellA = document.querySelector('.cellA');
    
    Name.innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${obj.name}</div>`;
    Code.innerHTML = `<div>Code: ${obj.code}</div>`;
    Spread.innerHTML = `<div>Spread: ${obj.spread}</div>`;
    CellA.innerHTML = `<div>Movement: ${obj['1day'].movement}</div><div>Price: ${obj['1day'].price}</div>`;
  });
}

fetchData();
```

Comment: why is not looping the html?

Comment: Simple - each time through the loop you assign data to the same elements as the last time through the loop, overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two .forEach() loops on 'data' and on the containing objects. Both are objects, which you can not iterate directly. Use

```js
Object.keys(obj)
Object.values(obj)
Object.entries(obj)
```

To get an iterable array with the data

In the snippet below this problem is solved an one object is displayed.
But there is still a logical problem. You only have four divs, which you are refilling every round, so only the data of the last is seen in the end.

Won't correct this since I think the main issue is solved with this.

```js
async function fetchData() {

  const response = await fetch('https://assets.cmcmarkets.com/json/cmc-test-most-popular-feed.json');
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log('data', data)

  Object.values(data).forEach(obj => {
    
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {

//       console.log(key, value);

      const Name = document.querySelector('.name'),
        Code = document.querySelector('.code'),
        Spread = document.querySelector('.spread'),
        CellA = document.querySelector('.cellA');


      if (key == "name") {
        Name.innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${value}</div>`;
      }

      if (key == "code") {
        Code.innerHTML = `<div>Code: ${value}</div>`;
      }

      if (key == "spread") {
        Spread.innerHTML = `<div>Spread: ${value}</div>`;
      } else if (key == "1day") {

      }

      //  data["X-ABFDN"]['1day']  data["X-ABAAA"]['1day']  data["X-AQWER"]['1day']
      else if (key == "1day") {
        CellA.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["movement"]}</div><div>price: ${data[key]["price"]}</div>`;

      }


    });


  });

}

fetchData();
```

```html
<div class="name"></div>
  <div class="code"></div>
  <div class="spread"></div>
  <div class="cellA"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 async function fetchData() {

const response = await fetch('https://assets.cmcmarkets.com/json/cmc-test-most-popular-feed.json');
const data = await response.json();
//console.log(data)

//This is the line you are missing
const dataArray = Object.values(data)
console.log(dataArray)

dataArray.forEach(obj => {
  console.log(obj);

  const Name = document.querySelector('.name');
  const Code = document.querySelector('.code')
  const Spread = document.querySelector('.spread');
  const CellA = document.querySelector('.cellA');

  Name.innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${obj.name}</div>`;
  Code.innerHTML = `<div>Code: ${obj.code}</div>`;
  Spread.innerHTML = `<div>Spread: ${obj.spread}</div>`;
  //CellA.innerHTML = `<div>CellA: ${obj.1day.movement}</div>`;
  //For 1day never start your variable nams with a number
});



 }

  fetchData();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).